# Code Working on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows

I am doing an internship in a company and I am developing an application that can manage the fleet of vehicles of this company, people can make reservations, see reservations, etc. And I have a page where people can see the reservations made. On my laptop where I'm using Linux(Antergos), I'm using Lamp to develop my application. In my Linux everything is working fine but when I tried the code in Windows using Wamp the page that lets you view the reservations is not working properly. *A fact aside*, I just started PHP since March so i m sorry if the code looks very rudimentary.

Here's how it should work(in Linux):
Working:
[image: Working]

Error:
Not Working:
[image: Not Working]

The error that gives is this:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: data_de_reserva in C: \ wamp64 \ www \ 1 \ ver_reservas.php on line 65 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0014255064 {main} () ... \ ver_reservas.php: 0 "/>

This is where i get my error:

```
<input name="calendario" type="text" id="calendario" size="10" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["data_de_reserva"]; ?>" />
```

And here is the rest of my code:

```
<?php
include 'connect_database.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Gestão de Viaturas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta">
    <link rel="icon" href="_imagens/favicon2.png">
    <style>
    body, td {
        font-size:12px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="_imagens/logo2.jpg" alt="logo">
  </div>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="home.php">Bem vindo <u><?php echo getenv('USERNAME');?></u></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reservas <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="reservas.php">Fazer Reservas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ver_reservas.php">Ver Reservas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Adminstração<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="apagar_reservas.php">Apagar Reservas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="adicionar.php">Adicionar Carros</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Saida do carro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Entrada do carro</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <div id="super">
      <div class="datagrid">
      </br>
      <form id="search_form" name="search_form" method="post" action="ver_reservas.php">
      <label for="calendario">Data</label>
      <input name="calendario" type="text" id="calendario" size="10" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["data_de_reserva"]; ?>" />
      <label>Carro</label>
      <select name="carro">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reservas GROUP BY carro_usado ORDER BY carro_usado";
        $query_result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row["carro_usado"]."'".
($row["carro_usado"]==$_REQUEST["carro_usado"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["carro_usado"]."</option>";
        }
      ?>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filtrar"/>
        </label>
        <a href="ver_reservas.php">Limpar</a>
      </form>
      </br>
      <table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <tr>
          <td width="110" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Nome</strong></td>
          <td width="110" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Carro</strong></td>
          <td width="110" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Data</strong></td>
          <td width="40" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Hora</strong></td>
          <td width="40" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Hora 
Prevista</strong></td>
          <td width="290" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<strong>Informação</strong></td>
        </tr>
      <?php
      if ($_REQUEST["carro"]<>'') {
        $search_carro = " AND 
carro_usado='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["carro"])."'";
      }

      if ($_REQUEST["calendario"]<>'') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE data_de_reserva = 
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["calendario"])."'".$search_carro;
      } elseif($_REQUEST["calendario"]<>'') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE id>0".$search_carro;
      } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE DATE(`data_de_reserva`) >= CURDATE()".$search_carro. "ORDER BY data_de_reserva";
      }

      $sql_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('request "Could 
not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
      ?>
      <?php $row["data_de_reserva"]  = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row["data_de_reserva"]));
            $row["hora"]  = date('H:i', strtotime($row["hora"]));
            $row["hora_prevista"]  = date('H:i', strtotime($row["hora_prevista"]));
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row["nome"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["carro_usado"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["data_de_reserva"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["hora"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["hora_prevista"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["informacao"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php
        }
      } else {
      ?>
      <tr><td colspan="6">Nenhum resultado encontrado.</td>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </table>

      <script>
        $(function() {
            var dates = $( "#calendario").datepicker({
                defaultDate: "",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                    var option = this.id,
                        instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                            instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                            $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                            selectedDate, instance.settings );
                    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var_dump your `$_REQUEST` var and compare output in both environments

Comment: value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST["data_de_reserva"]){ echo $_REQUEST["data_de_reserva"]; }" ?>... try this on input value

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs both of them gives null

Comment: @Aeonar then look into isset :) that should help get rid of the errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php but with why it differs on OS not sure

Comment: @BilalAhmed Doesn't show up the notice anymore, but still can't see my reservations

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Okay, I will look into that :) I will let you know if i can make it work. Thx for the help.